# C# convert magnitude/phase to real/imaginary

Tags: c#, math

If I'm given the Polar coordinates of a Fourier transform and I want to go back to the Cartesian (Real/Imaginary) coordiates, how would I go about doing that?

I'm able to get the Polar numbers from the Cartesian coordiates with the following code:

```
    private double GetPhase(double real, double imaginary)
    {
         return Math.Atan2(imaginary, real);
    }

    private double GetMagnitude(double real, double imaginary)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt((real * real) + (imaginary * imaginary));
    }
```

But how do I go back?

Comment: This is really a math question, not about programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't that just:

(pseudocode)

```
x = cos(angle) * magnitude
y = sin(angle) * magnitude
```

(use negative sin if you're using computer's inverted coordinate system)
?

Comment: I do believe that is correct!  In 6 mins I will accept your answer :) I knew it was something simple like that!

Answer (score 1):

To add to @BlueMonkMN's answer:

```
private  double GetX (double angle, double magnitude)
{
    return Math.Cos(angle) * magnitude;
}

private  double GetY (double angle, double magnitude)
{
    return Math.Sin(angle) * magnitude;
}
```